# Run a php script automatically without opening in browser

Tags: php, cron

I have a php script which I call via curl to get the prices of "flipkart products" (about 500 product). I have to run the script everyday to know changes in prices of products.

Is there any way that the script can be run automatically at a specified time, say at 12:00 PM everyday, so that prices are automatically updated in the database.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18737407/how-to-create-cron-job-using-php

Comment: Use cron job for it.. set it in control panel of server.